# Creating a custom button from an image with rounded sides in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, button, flutter-layout

I would like to create a custom button from an image in Flutter.

I've created the following image to be used as the background for the button:

[image]

As you can see, the sides of the button image have a **perfectly rounded half-circle shape**.

My requirements for the button are:

1. The half-circle sides of the button should remain perfectly rounded (i.e. not get stretched).
2. Only the middle part of the button's image should stretch in order to accommodate its content.
3. The button can't have a fixed size, and should grow according to its content.
4. The button's content should overlap with the half circle areas of the button.

Ideally, it should look something like this:

[image]

I've created the following button Widget in Flutter:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final double fontSize;

  const MyButton({Key? key, required this.text, required this.fontSize})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {},
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage('assets/images/my-button.png'),
              fit: BoxFit.fill),
        ),
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(24),
          child: Text(text,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: fontSize, color: Colors.white)),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Using the Widget above, I've created 4 buttons:

```dart
Column(children: [
    MyButton(text: 'Play', fontSize: 32.0),
    MyButton(text: 'Settings', fontSize: 32.0),
    MyButton(text: 'Very very very very very very long text', fontSize: 20.0),
    MyButton(text: 'Small', fontSize: 12.0)
])
```

This resulted in the following buttons:

[image]

Now as you can see, the half-circle sides of the buttons **are now stretched up/down**, and are **no longer perfectly rounded**.

One of the many things I've tried was playing with the `centerSlice` attribute of the `DecorationImage` Widget which looked promising, but the button's sides would stay perfectly rounded only when the button's height was exactly the height of my image (conflicting with requirement #3 listed above).

How can I create a button that meets the requirements I've listed above?

Answer (score 0):

You need to maintain the image width, others fit doesn't looks better imo. Follow this structure, it will provide a little better look

```dart
return GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {},
  child: Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(24),
    clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24),
      image: DecorationImage(
        image: AssetImage('assets/images/my-button.png'),
        fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
      ),
    ),
    child: Text(text,
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: fontSize, color: Colors.white)),
  ),
);
```

[image]

Comment: The problem with clipping the image in the Widget is that you cut out some of the details (the two starts in this case), which I would like to preserve.

Comment: you can try with  `fit: BoxFit.fill`

Comment: ```BoxFit.fill``` is the attribute that I've used in my original post, but it results in stretched corners (and not perfectly-rounded).

Comment: What I can think of making it better by slicing two star, and on middle portion fill it with color/image<BoxFit.fill>